# How to stop memory warning when using custom UICollectionViewCell in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What could I be doing wrong? I've uploaded a few jpeg image using parse.com dashboard and set some other data such as title and price. When scrolling through my collectionView on my device it's choppy then eventually crashes.

**Here is the code:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self objects] count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    NSArray *people = [self objects];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    VAGGarmentCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    PFObject *current;

    current = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    PFFile *userImageFile = current[@"image"];

    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        [[cell contentView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [[cell imageView] setImage:image];

    }];

    [[cell title] setText:[current valueForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell price] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"£%@", [current valueForKey:@"price"]]];

    return cell;

}
```

I have a strong feeling it's something to do with my images. I hope someone can help me solve this issue. This is the first time I've dealt with collection view.

Thanks for your time.
Kind regards.

Comment: Can you NSlog your image size and check what size the actual image is in the collection view

Comment: Crashes with what exception? It might have something to do with the method that downloads the image. You might consider using something like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) instead.

Comment: @andreamazz I get a "terminated due to memory pressure" message.

Comment: @JSA986 image size is 2480.00 x 3508.00 (using NSLog(@"%.2f",image.size.width); NSLog(@"%.2f",image.size.height);)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image size is whats causing your memory issues in your collection view and choppy scrolling.  Resize your image,  add the re sized image to your collection view

```
//resize image
CGSize destinationSize = CGSizeMake(264,476);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width, destinationSize.height)];

//New image
UIImage*newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Optimise image
NSData *imageDataCompressed = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.4f);
                    NSLog(@"Image Size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(newImage.size));//log size of image
```

Comment: Crashing has stopped but still very choppy when scrolling. Can see cells replacing image with different images.

Comment: I've taken another look and removed images and labels etc. There was still chopping. I removed the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock  block and the chopping was gone. It's clearly something to do with the images being loaded in the background. My UITable code is nearly identical to this and that works fine. Not sure what's so different here.